# Using $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser() in another class

Tags: symfony

I would like to get current userid like this in one class(FOSUBUserProvider)

```
$this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()
```

but it says

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Call to undefined method Acme\UserBundle\Security\Core\User\FOSUBUserProvider::get() in
```

I think I should inject something in this class though,

How can I do it?

My construct is this, how can I add here security.context?

```
class FOSUBUserProvider extends BaseClass
{

    public function __construct(UserManagerInterface $userManager, array $properties)
    {
        $this->userManager = $userManager;
        $this->properties  = $properties;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reason**

`FOSUBUserProvider` doesn't have container injected so `$this->get()` won't work (alias for `$this->container->get()`)

**Solution**

if you want to access `security.context` service then easiest and I think the most elegant way would be to extend `FOSUBUserProvider` in your bundle.

to do so create new class that extends: `HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Core\User\FOSUBUserProvider`

Please note that `array $properties` must be the last argument, I injected $securityContext between them. This is necessary because we override service definition and later it will have appended arguments. (Quite advanced topic not relevant here)

```
namespace KP\MainBundle\Security\Core\User;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface;
use HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Core\User\FOSUBUserProvider as BaseFOSUBUserProvider;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;


class FOSUBUserProvider extends BaseFOSUBUserProvider
{
    /**
     * @var SecurityContext
     */
    protected $securityContext;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param UserManagerInterface $userManager     FOSUB user provider.
     * @param SecurityContext      $securityContext Security context
     * @param array                $properties      Property mapping.
     */
    public function __construct(UserManagerInterface $userManager, $securityContext, array $properties)
    {
        $this->userManager = $userManager;
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
        $this->properties  = $properties;
    }
}
```

Override class name used by HWIOAuthBundle add in your services file

```
parameter:
    hwi_oauth.user.provider.fosub_bridge.class: KP\MainBundle\Security\Core\User\FOSUBUserProvider

services:
    hwi_oauth.user.provider.fosub_bridge.def:
        class: %hwi_oauth.user.provider.fosub_bridge.class%
        abstract: true
        arguments:
            - @fos_user.user_manager
            - @security.context
```

**Important note**

Your bundle must be registered AFTER `HWIOAuthBundle`, otherwise overriding service won't work.

```
# app/AppKernel.php
$bundles = array(
        ...
        new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
        new HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\HWIOAuthBundle(),
        new KP\MainBundle\KPMainBundle(),
        ...
```

Now you can access `SecurityContext` service with simple `$this->securityContext`

Comment: THanks, I am trying now. But I just wonder where can I pass the argument to __construct?? I think I should setup in service.yml maybe..

Comment: @whitebear oh, sorry. I edited my answer, now service.yml contain valid service definition.

Comment: It looks to have only two arguments. error message says Argument 3 passed to Acme\UserBundle\Security\Core\User\FOSUBUserProvider::__construct() must be of the type array, none given

Comment: @whitebear I forgot about ```abstract: true``` in the service.yml, see edited answer now

Comment: error doesnt change ,,I am not sure what abstract:true means , does it slove that there is not third argument?. ErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 3 passed to Acme\UserBundle\Security\Core\User\FOSUBUserProvider::__construct() must be of the type array, none given

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45620/discussion-between-konrad-podgorski-and-whitebear)

Comment: Finally I can slove he problem,I re-write the whole config.yml and security.yml according to this sample https://gist.github.com/danvbe/4476697 I couldn't find the reason though, your sample cord is surely correct.THanks very much